# Ratio of column widths based on font size

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, resize, multiple-columns

I am trying to automate the sizing of the columns in a 2-column table in a Word document using a VBA code (actually using the `Office.Interop` from C#).

What I try to achieve is the optimal width ratio to have the shortest page count. Much like the automatic alignment of an html table.

I am converting the following VBA code to C# that increments the width and recalculates the pages to see if the count decreases and stops once it reached the lowest count (actually it steps back one step when the page count starts to increase again).

```vb
j = 50   'Arbitrarily set width to 50 points

Do
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=j, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustProportional

    j = j + 5
    ActiveDocument.Repaginate
    Application.ScreenRefresh
    DoEvents
    If ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages") > PgNum And j > 55 Then
        Do
            j = j - 1
            Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=j, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustProportional

            ActiveDocument.Repaginate
            Application.ScreenRefresh

        Loop Until PgNum = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")
        Exit Do
    Else
        PgNum = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")
    End If
Loop
```

This works fine in Word and does what I need, however it is rather robust and slow. What I am trying to come up with is a calculation where from the font size I get the exact ratio.

So instead of converting the above code to C# using the `Office.Interop` I want to convert this with a simple line of code that calculates the correct ratio instead of the trial and error.

The sum of the width of the 2 columns is always 540. All text formatting is negligible, the only determining factor is the font size in each of the columns (the font size is consistent within the given column).

The values that I have are for 3 different font sizes:

```
 1. Col1: 7   Col2: 14   Width: Col1: 15%     Col2: 85%
 2. Col1: 8   Col2: 14   Width: Col1: 18.5%   Col2: 81.5%
 3. Col1: 10  Col2: 14   Width: Col1: 25%     Col2: 75%
```

I have spent quite some time on trying to figure out a calculation, but have not been able to come up with a sensible way of doing this. I read many articles about the font size ratios, but none of them lead to a solution yet.

**Update:**

I came up finally with the following calculation:

```
Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=540/3.375*Font1Size*(Log(Font1Size)/Log(11.5)+0.243)/Font2Size
Selection.Tables(1).Columns(2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=540-(540/3.375*Font1Size*(Log(Font1Size)/Log(11.5)+0.243)/Font2Size)
```

Any idea of a simpler approach?